# Unable to Save and Edit credentials.yml.enc in Rubymine or Vim for Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rubymine

I am trying to add an API key and token to my credentials.yml.enc file in Rubymine. I can't seem to find a --wait flag or save the generated file from

```
EDITOR=rubymine rails credentials:edit
```

or

```
EDITOR="rubymine --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

What happens is I add my keys to the file for example:

```
api_client:
  api_key: 123
```

but just by opening the file I see a

```
File encrypted and saved.
```

message before I can enter anything, so when I spin up my rails console to test my keys like:

```
 Rails.application.credentials.api_client[:api_key]
```

I just get back a 'nil' value error.

When I try to edit in vim I get similar results. I can't seem to find any answers online, I am running ruby '2.6.3' with Rails 6.0.2.2 on MacOS Catalina 10.15.4. Thank you all for your time.

---

Solution: at this time I have found that using a different editor (ATOM) solves the short term problem. I will continue to try and understand if rubymine has this capability as well.

Comment: Have you tried using other editor?

Answer (score 7):

Try this..
`EDITOR="vim" bin/rails credentials:edit`
Works like charm with MacOS Catalina

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
EDITOR = "/Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/MacOS/rubymine --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

in macOS Big Sur that is.

Answer (score 4):

I also got "File encrypted and saved." trying to run `EDITOR="vim" bin/rails credentials:edit` in a Rails 6.1 project.

It was simply a matter of the editor not being installed – I tried just the `vim` command to confirm this. After installing Vim (`apt-get install vim` on this Ubuntu system), it worked as expected.

Comment: I have vim installed as I use it as a primary editor and I get this error locally. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, assuming you get this error even when running with an explicit editor like `EDITOR="vim" bin/rails credentials:edit` and `which vim` shows an installed Vim.

Comment: I figured the issue was due to an alias I use that looks like `set RAILS_ENV development && bin/rails`. I changed it to `RAILS_ENV=development bin/rails` and it's working. I have no clue about the why tho.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue when trying to use Atom. I realised that I needed to install the Atom shell commands:

Click Atom → Install Shell Commands

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For macOS you can use the following command to open in RubyMine:-

```
EDITOR="/Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/MacOS/rubymine --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE!

```
VISUAL='kate --block' bin/rails credentials:edit
```

I'm using kate as a visual editor with linux and the '--block' flag is for wait to close the editor to save and encrypt the credentials

Answer (score 0):

I use this one,

```
EDITOR="nano" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

nano works for me to edit secret credentails.